# Creating newline after every 5 spaces

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a string from a json file that I need to insert a `\n` into every 5 words. I tried manually splitting every 5 words of the string, but since it is a random string every time, that is futile. The code is as follows:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import requests

root = tk.Tk()

root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

link = requests.get('https://talaikis.com/api/quotes/random/')
RESPONSE = link.json()['quote']   
RESPONSE2 = link.json()['author']
new = RESPONSE.split(" ")

l = []
l.append(sum(len(s) for s in new[0:5]))
l.append(sum(len(s) for s in new[5:10]))
l.append(sum(len(s) for s in new[10:15]))
l.append(sum(len(s) for s in new[15:20]))
l.append(sum(len(s) for s in new[20:25]))
l.append(sum(len(s) for s in new[25:30]))
l.append(sum(len(s) for s in new[30:35]))
l.append(sum(len(s) for s in new[35:40]))
l.append(sum(len(s) for s in new[40:45]))
l.append(sum(len(s) for s in new[45:50]))
l.append(sum(len(s) for s in new[50:55]))
x = list(set(l))
x.sort(reverse=True)

message = Label(root, text = RESPONSE + "\n-" + RESPONSE2, height=round(len(new)/5), width = x[0])
message.pack(side = tk.BOTTOM)
root.mainloop()
```

As seen from the whole l list ordeal, in my attempt to find the longest line, it is extremely non-pythonic and some ugly code. I need to find a faster way to split every 5 words.

Comment: So if your "response" is this: "a b c d e f g h i j k" Are you trying to reach this: "a b c d e \n f g h i j \n k \n"?

Comment: Yeah pretty much. Kabanus' answer got it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you see the same pattern popping up, that always begs a loop. Your method is fine, but instead of manually jumping 5, you could for example:

```
res = ''
for i in range(0,len(new),5):
    res += (' '.join(new[i:i+5]) + " \n ")
```

I'm not sure of you want to aggregate the lines in a list and then sort, but you can easily amend this code to do that.

There are quite a few ways to do this in Python, some more some less Pyhtonic, but I think this encapsulates the logic of your solution.